# Failed audit for trying to close a off topic question

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I recently came across [3rd Week of Programming, just looking for tips](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25382192/2991525) in the Close Review queue and failed the audit, because I voted for close and obviously the audit expected me to click *Leave Open*.

---

[image: This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit.]

---

But what really surprised me was, that the post was put *on hold* for being *off topic* 7 hours before I reviewed it. (I needed significantly less than 7h for the review; approx. 5 min)

Why was this question chosen as a audit? It doesn't seem to be a good example for posts that should **not** be closed, if it's already *on hold*.

---

*BTW:* At the time i reviewed it, the question had 5 upvotes vs. 0 downvotes, so if votes was the only criterion, it was clearly a high quality question.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have the page open for a long time or anything like that? If not, I believe this is a bug.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: I guess i had a look at the question for about 5 min at most, but certainly not 6h+.

Comment: @iStimple: It was even +5 / -0 when I reviewed it.

Comment: I'm assuming (while investigating) that the audit choice was stored while it looked promising; thanks for getting it right, even if the system disagreed; I'll see if we can improve this

Comment: You know, there is actually a term in the training world for this. It's called "negative transfer of training." The audit system, in so doing, is actually trying to produce students who are worse than they would have been had they never been taught.