# Should votes (up-votes, down-votes) be audited?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, voting

We currently have an automated audit process for reviewers who decide whether or not to approve edits, close questions, etc.  As [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359408/audit-questions-also-teach-so-why-arent-they-manually-cultivated) points out, the automated audit process doesn't work very well for reviews.

However, it would be a shame to toss out all of that good automated post-selecting code. Why not repurpose it to catch robo-voters? It seems that there could be legitimate purpose in educating voters on when they should have down-voted a question, or when they should not have up-voted, perhaps?

As the [voting guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) say:

> Voting up a question or answer signals to the rest of the community
>   that a post is interesting, well-researched, and useful, while voting
>   down a post signals the opposite: that the post contains wrong
>   information, is poorly researched, or fails to communicate
>   information.

If a user consistently sabotages this, and enough users do that, it can cause harm. I do think there is a tendency to dismiss this as "noise" - but that is a statistical concept that can only be understood in the context of an emergent collection of questions and answers, and has no usefulness when looking at an individual question.

This feature might pop up a message after a user up-votes a question which has a number of down votes, close votes, or the like, asking the user to examine the question and confirm their vote.  Or, if a user down-votes a question or answer with a significant number of up-votes, perhaps it could prompt the user to provide feedback or edit the question if they think it needs improvement. In no circumstance should the user be blocked from voting.

What do you think?

Comment: up and downvotes are VERY personal. Not sure that saying "everyone else upvoted this, you should have to" is the Stack way

Comment: Downvotes and upvotes have always been your own, as long as you vote on content and not target people you can vote as you please, there is no correct way to vote. This is a fundamental part of SO, implementing your suggestions will greatly change this site.

Comment: I know the way it has always been done. I think there could be an implementation that doesn't change the site in a negative way. @Patrice, I agree that voting is "personal" in the sense that it applies to a single post. I don't agree that voting is purely subjective, as that would imply that up-votes and down-votes are arbitrary, which they are clearly not.

Comment: @TheMayer Never said they were purely subjective (but they definitely have a GOOD amount of subjectivity to them). But unless we are talking about upvoted off-topic stuff, I don't see how we should regulate that kind of thing. Frankly. Unless I am upvoting a question that should be closed, I will be very happy keeping my upvote an upvote, even if the community disagrees with me. even the best answers we have have 1-2 downvotes that came in during the years. Mostly because somewhere, someone disagreed/thought they had a better answer. These downvotes aren't invalid.

Comment: Certainly, but I'm not saying the system should keep you from voting- but wouldn't there be value in annoying people who habitually vote the opposite way of the generally-accepted voting patterns?

Comment: So "blind mice" users upvote an answer that is completely wrong.  And someone comes along and downvotes it.  You want to make this person who was the only one to vote correctly to justify his vote by confirming and explaining it?

Comment: I would hope the algorithms could be more selective than that...

Comment: How? If you go by number of votes... how will the system differentiate "you are downvoting an answer where 10 people blindly upvoted" and "you are downvoting an answer where 10 people upvoted justly"? (we VERY often have people here complain about "mob voting". If the mob voting is wrong, it makes sense to go against it, and your warning would come off as "you are doing something wrong!")

Comment: I'm not proposing an implementation, I am merely proposing an idea. It is up to people smarter than me to figure out how to implement it in a way that doesn't produce spurious results :)

Comment: @TheMayer https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info, normally, for Feature Request tag, it's actually expected that you provide a bunch of details about your suggested feature

Comment: @theMayer: "*but wouldn't there be value in annoying people who habitually vote the opposite way of the generally-accepted voting patterns?*" No. Such a system by its nature presupposes that the majority are correct. Which means if an answer was upvoted by a lot of people, downvoting it is bad even if the answer is outdated or simply wrong-but-popular. No, we don't need this.

Comment: related: [Is using an up-vote to balance out a down-vote wrong?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311406/839601)

Comment: I feel like I've seen this same question asked recently...

Comment: I would like to see how to audit controversial post having amount of both legitimate upvote and downvote

Comment: I guess the inquisition can start with the one person currently who upvoted this question in the teeth of all the other downvoters. Do you think that just because they agree with you they should be banned from further voting? If so why shouldn't you be banned too? You'd be the cause of their ban.

Comment: `If a user consistently sabotages this, and enough users do that, it can cause harm.` That sounds like an imagineered problem. There is zero incentive to behave like this. There's nothing to be gained from it and no viable cause for a group of like-minded users to unite under.

Comment: And forgetting about people who vote "wrong" - once you start digging into why people vote, you start running into serious complications.  What about a "correct" answer that has a serious security flaw or is a bad practice.  People might upvote it because it is correct, other might downvote it because of the flaw or poor practice.  And then you get into answers that were correct but circumstances changed and it is no longer correct.  There are always cases when some people may correctly vote against the majority.  And who to say either is correct.

Comment: If someone downvotes due to a security flaw, wouldn't you expect that person to leave a comment as to the flaw?

Comment: @TheMayer that's the ideal situation. But not something we want to enforce. In any case, should we badger that user with "everyone  else thinks this is a great answer. Think twice before downvoting it?"

Comment: Not necessarily. But I’ve seen downvotes on my answers (or questions) with no explanation whatsoever. I think a downvote is akin to a negative review on a business. Sure, you can leave two stars, but if the business cares about its customers, it wants to know where it could have delivered value where it did not. Similarly, if a user habitually upvotes questions that are later closed or answers that are deleted, that seems like something that could be detected and used to thwart such behavior. I have no doubt such users exist, potentially in bulk.

Comment: @theMayer actually explaining downvotes is discouraged because it doesn't lead anywhere good.  You end up with arguments and hurt feelings, or you have someone engage is revenge downvoting.  What is encouraged is comments that suggest how to improve the post.  So no, just because someone downvoted doesn't mean there should be a comment.  Only someone who can help improve the answer should comment

Answer (score 25):

No, voting as described in this post should not be audited. Just because 100 other people upvoted doesn't mean the post is the gold standard.

I have seen some 100+ posts which were not correct. What would auditing my downvote in those circumstances gain? Force me to explain the downvote? That topic has been covered already, in multiple places - it all boils down to no. It is also probably the primary source of downvotes for your feature-request.

As far as user sabotage, that sounds far fetched to me, we would need some sort of factual basis for that.

I like that you are trying to come up with ways to improve the overall system, but perhaps you should start by looking at some of the posts in the [se-quality-project tag at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/se-quality-project) for an idea of what has been done more recently, and where your input would cover new ground.

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a good idea. The reason review audits work (though they aren't perfect as you pointed out) is because all actions that you can take in the review queue are also possible to take outside of the review queue. So if you fail an incorrect audit, you can (and are encouraged to) take the opposite action outside of the review queue, which is why review audits only stop robo-reviewers and not people who are really sure about what they're doing.

Voting is different, since you already vote directly on the post and there is no way to vote without clicking on the vote button. If you fail a bad review audit, you can open the post in a new tab and take the correct action from there. But what do you do if you fail a bad voting audit? The system already stopped you from voting on the post correctly, and there is no way you can get around this to vote on the post correctly without voting. So you're stuck being forced to think that a good post is a bad one or that a bad post is a good one.

There are a lot of bad answers out there which have a positive score and on which downvotes should be allowed.

For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4339977/4284627) is accepted and has a score of 7 even though it doesn't answer the question (all it does is it suggests a workaround when the other answers actually provide an answer).

Even worse, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1867739/4284627) is completely wrong. Now it has a score of -2, which is good, but when I saw it the first time, it had 2 upvotes and no downvotes; I was the first one to downvote it. After I downvoted it, 3 other users also did, which is good. But if there were voting audits as you suggest, this answer could have been chosen as a voting audit at the time it had 2 upvotes and no downvotes, telling me and the 3 other users who downvoted it that we're wrong, when it actually is the answer that's wrong. That would lead to a wrong answer having 2 upvotes, and nobody would have the possibility to downvote it. You don't want that, do you?

---

Besides, what good would voting audits do? You mention users voting incorrectly. I can think of several reasons why they would vote incorrectly, but none of them would be solved by voting audits:

- I would interpret the way you wrote your question as that you think people are intentionally voting incorrectly to sabotage the system. That sounds far-fetched to me. There might be one user who does that on one post, but the problem is clearly not big enough for there to be any need to do anything about it (if there even is a problem, which I doubt).
- Users can also vote incorrectly because they're serial voting. But there are already ways to handle this. There is a script that reverses serial voting, and users who do it too often can get suspended for voting irregularities. This stops serial voting a lot better than voting audits would.
- Another reason why people could vote incorrectly (though I've seen no evidence of this) would be robo-voting: like for robo-reviewing, people carelessly vote on everything they see just for the badges. I've never seen any evidence of this happening, but even if it were a problem, voting audits wouldn't be a solution.

  If there were voting audits, people who could see the score would just upvote everything that has a positive score and downvote everything having a negative score in order not to be caught by audits, and the audits would be useless.

  Of course, the score could be faked like it is in review audits, but I would find it very frustrating if I'm looking for an answer to a programming problem and the best answer with everything I need is all the way on the bottom just for an audit's sake.

  Besides, if people go around robo-voting just for the badges, they would probably do it from the home page or the *Questions* page where most posts were posted just a few minutes ago and have 0 score and therefore wouldn't be selected as audits.

For these reasons, I think that voting audits would be harmful and not do any good.